# Very weird - Why is only ONE BONE flipped weird (Blender to Unity)?

Tags: animation, export, unity, shape-keys, .fbx

Ok I have tried everything here. I have a model that Ive exported to Unity as FBX, using the NLA editor all following a tutorial. Everything is great EXCEPT one bone (or combination - its the left leg) are flipped upside down.

So the animations all play, but that bone is just flipped -

Here is Blender, where Ive tested with removing ALL keyframes from that leg, still no luck:

[image]

And Unity:

[image]

What is wrong here?